# Appcenter Freezing. Searching for three letters

Tags: appcenter

When searching at the Appcenter, entering three characters froze the Appcenter.
***"io.elementary.appcenter" window does not respond.***

[image]

So I compeltely removed the Appcenter
*$ sudo apt-get purge appcenter*
I have also removed the remaining packages associated with Appcenter.

I've installed the Appcenter again.
*$ sudo apt install appcenter*
And I've made updates in the Appcenter.

Likewise, entering three characters froze the Appcenter.
Other than that it works well.
Installing, uninstalling, updating, works fine.
However, when searching for three letters, it froze.

I'm Korean. This is Korea.
Do you have any conflicts with Korean input method?
The Korean input method uses 'nimf'.
['nimf'](https://cogniti.github.io/nimf/) works fine without any problems.

When searching in Appcenter, of course, search in English.

Comment: I don't know a solution, but have you tried another input method, like uim-byeoru?

Answer (score 1):

I came back.
You said I was coming back..
re-install eOS. However, I did not install Korean input method (nimf).
Searching in Appcenter works good(quickly).
I install Korean input method. I use Korean input method, nimf Korean input method.
It stops when it searches in Appcenter.
end.
Bye bye.

currently, iBus input method on eOS does not work in Korean language.
fcitx has more problems than nimf.
nimf is not searchable in Appcenter.
So, it's hard to use Korean.
By the way, the elementary OS is pretty.
pretty...

Really goodbye.

Comment: I would recommend  opening an issue at: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/